# Why is my count query on index field slow?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following schema:

```
leadgenie-django=> \d main_lead;
                Table "public.main_lead"
     Column      |           Type           | Modifiers
-----------------+--------------------------+-----------
 id              | uuid                     | not null
 body            | text                     | not null
 username        | character varying(255)   | not null
 link            | character varying(255)   | not null
 source          | character varying(10)    | not null
 keyword_matches | character varying(255)[] | not null
 json            | jsonb                    | not null
 created_at      | timestamp with time zone | not null
 updated_at      | timestamp with time zone | not null
 campaign_id     | uuid                     | not null
 is_accepted     | boolean                  |
 is_closed       | integer                  |
 raw_body        | text                     |
 accepted_at     | timestamp with time zone |
 closed_at       | timestamp with time zone |
 score           | double precision         |
Indexes:
    "main_lead_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "main_lead_campaign_id_75034b1f" btree (campaign_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "main_lead_campaign_id_75034b1f_fk_main_campaign_id" FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id) REFERENCES main_campaign(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

As you can see, `campaign_id` is indexed.

When I do a simple `WHERE` with a `campaign_id`, the query still takes 16 seconds.

```
leadgenie-django=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE select count(*) from main_lead where campaign_id = '9a183263-7a60-4ec0-a354-2175f8a2e5c9';
                                                          QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=202866.79..202866.80 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=16715.762..16715.763 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on main_lead  (cost=0.00..202189.94 rows=270739 width=0) (actual time=1143.886..16516.490 rows=279405 loops=1)
         Filter: (campaign_id = '9a183263-7a60-4ec0-a354-2175f8a2e5c9'::uuid)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 857300
 Planning time: 0.080 ms
 Execution time: 16715.807 ms
```

I would have expected this query to be fast (under 1s), since this field is indexed. Is there a reason my expectation is wrong? Anything I could do to speed it up?

Comment: campaign_id is a low-cardinality column.

Comment: Seems like I'd have to cache the count then? Any other way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126997/postgresql-not-using-index-during-count could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The query fetches about 25% of your table, so PostgreSQL thinks that this is most cheaply done with a sequential scan of the whole table. That is probably correct.

Try running

```
VACUUM main_lead;
```

That will update the *visibility map*, and if there are no long-running concurrent transactions, that should mark most of the table blocks as all-visible, so that you can get a faster *index only scan* for the query.